# How to open mat-menu on keyup

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, material-ui

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="floatAlways" appearance="standard">
   <mat-label
      [ngStyle]="{'color': password.errors?.required && floatAlways == 'always'? 'red' : '' }">
      Password
   </mat-label>
   <input [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" type="password" matInput
   (keyup)="validatePassword($event)"
   [formControl]="password"
   placeholder=" " #confirmPassword>
   <password-visibility-control matSuffix [inputElement]="confirmPassword">
   </password-visibility-control>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before" class="status-menu">
   <div>
      <button mat-menu-item disabled>
      <span *ngIf="!alphanumeric"> <img class="circle-icon mb-1"
         src="assets/icons/blank_circle.svg" alt=""
         style="height: 11px;width: 11px;" /> Alpha
      numeric</span>
      <span *ngIf="alphanumeric"> <img class="circle-icon mb-1"
         src="assets/icons/check.svg" alt=""
         style="height: 11px;width: 11px;" /> Alpha
      numeric</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div>
      <button mat-menu-item disabled>
      <span *ngIf="!capitalLetter"> <img class="circle-icon mb-1"
         src="assets/icons/blank_circle.svg" alt=""
         style="height: 11px;width: 11px;" /> Upper case
      alphabet</span>
      <span *ngIf="capitalLetter"> <img class="circle-icon mb-1"
         src="assets/icons/check.svg" alt=""
         style="height: 11px;width: 11px;" /> Upper case
      alphabet</span>
      </button>
   </div>
</mat-menu>
```

[image]

Actually in scenrio 1: When i clicked into password field its open which is good
but when i click outside the menu is closed so when i type something from keyboard the menu is not opening so i need to open menu every time when i click to type password.

Comment: Seems like it would be much easier to use mat-hint here as this is exactly what it is meant for.

Comment: Yes we can but it will not fulfil requirement anyways I got the solution

Comment: <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="floatAlways" appearance="standard"  
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"    (menuOpened)="menuOpened()">
  </mat-form-field>

Comment: Finally my problem is soved by placing   [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" in mat-form-filed tag

Comment: Could you please post the answer?